# LocalDate when passed to DatePicker shows the wrong value in android

Tags: android

I have a textview and when I click on it, datepicker dialog opens up. I am trying to display today's date on the datepicker dialog. If today is October 11, 2021, the datepicker dialog shows Novermber 11, 2021. But when I select the dates, the textview shows the correct date which is October 11, 2021. The problem is the month which is for some reason up by one.

```
public View.OnClickListener openDatePicker = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String todaysDate = LocalDate.now().toString();
        Log.i("todays date", todaysDate);

        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(todaysDate, formatter);
        openDatePickerForParty(localDate);
    }
};


public void openDatePickerForParty(LocalDate givenLocalDT){

    DatePickerDialog startDateDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
            AddNewEventScreen.this.textViewEventDate.setText(year + "-"+ (month) + "-" + day);
        }
    }, givenLocalDT.getYear(), givenLocalDT.getMonthValue(), givenLocalDT.getDayOfMonth());
    Log.i("thismonth", String.valueOf(givenLocalDT.getMonthValue()));
    startDateDialog.show();
}
```

The Log "thismonth" also displays the correct month of 10.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for confusion here is the fact that **DatePickerDialog** widget accepts month value from 0 to 11.

> monthOfYear -----> int: the initially selected month of the year (0-11 for compatibility with Calendar#MONTH)

So when you pass 10 for October for it its November. Just subtract the month value by 1 before initializing the DatePickerDailog and then its all fine. More info [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog#DatePickerDialog(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener,%20int,%20int,%20int))